# Add JSON Package Reference; new to Java

Tags: java, eclipse, json, json-simple

I'm brand new to Java and have always been a c kind-of-guy. That being said, I'm trying to use the JSON libraries (packages? classes? Java terminology is so damn confusing!) and am having issues adding them as a reference.

These three imports cannot be resolved:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
```

I went to json.org and [downloaded](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) the Java libraries but I'm not sure what to do with them. I've tried to go into project properties and add an external class to no avail. I noticed the downloaded folder is full of .java files. What am I supposed to do with these?

Sorry to present such a noob question on here, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Think of a `.jar` as a static library in C. When you compile your code you have to explicitly tell `javac` where those jars are. If you're using an IDE there will be a way to add them to your project, otherwise you have to use `-classpath /my/jar/file.jar` with `javac`

Comment: Why static? JAR is DLL/SO/SL! ;)

Comment: Yeah ... I was thinking about that after I wrote it but it's late. It's a dynamic library provided you have multiple apps running in the same VM and pulling it from the same classloader ... which would confuse him even more :-D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a wrong download I believe. You need JSON-Simple library from here http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ . Your link points to another implementation.

After download the *.jar should be added to the classpath. How you do it depends on the tools you use. In Eclipse it is right-click on the project, Properties->Libraries and add the new JAR.

Comment: The jar present on the URL is down now. Any other links available to download the json jar?

Answer (score 18):

- Right click on the Eclipse project,
- choose Properties
- Select Java Build Path
- Click the libraries tab
- click add external jars
- find the json jar(s) and add them.

Comment: Why isn't this at the top. Methinks SO needs to reevaluate their criteria for a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Hey just download the json.jar from this website

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm

after that

- right click on your eclipse project then
- choose Properties of that folder
- Select Java Build Path Click the libraries tab
- click add external jars

find the json jar(s) and add them.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

and add these package in your java file :)

Comment: I could't download jar from given location

Comment: url is accessible or search on google there are other sites available

Answer (score 1):

Be advised: Json and JsonSimple are not the same.  If you are using Maven you can get json-simple by adding this dependency to your pom file:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```